# Odoo POS receipt need to add address from res.partner city in receipt

Tags: javascript, odoo, odoo-10

I don't know how to add `res.partner` object in below `screen.js`

```js
print_xml: function() {
  var env = {
    widget: this,
    pos: this.pos,
    order: this.pos.get_order(),
    receipt: this.pos.get_order().export_for_printing(),
    paymentlines: this.pos.get_order().get_paymentlines()
  };
  render_receipt: function() {
    var order = this.pos.get_order();
    this.$('.pos-receipt-container').html(QWeb.render('PosTicket',{
      widget:this,
      order: order,
      partner:partner,
      receipt: order.export_for_printing(),
      orderlines: order.get_orderlines(),
      paymentlines: order.get_paymentlines(),
    }));
  };
};
```

I have tried to add the partner object in above javascript but it's not working.
I am new in odoo and i have also not munch knowledge of JavaScript so pls help me to solve this issue.
If i am able to add `res.partner` object in this javascript file then and then only i m available to access the `res.partner` objcet in my `pos.xml` file.

**I wan't the address details of company and it's not in res_company so how can i fetch the street and other address from res_partner for company ?**

Comment: Must you edit the javascript file to add  a address in receipt? Did you try with the Qweb template or Python part?

Comment: @julivico yes i was try it but it's not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get it using get_client() method.

You will get full object of the partner of current order then you can use it as like a py file eg. `partner.city` etc. in the receipt template.

```
render_receipt: function() {
    var order = this.pos.get_order();
    this.$('.pos-receipt-container').html(QWeb.render('PosTicket',{
      widget:this,
      order: order,
      partner:this.pos.get_order().get_client(),
      receipt: order.export_for_printing(),
      orderlines: order.get_orderlines(),
      paymentlines: order.get_paymentlines(),
    }));
  };
```

**Update:**

To add address fields in res.company model in js.

```
var module = require('point_of_sale.models');
var models = module.PosModel.prototype.models;
for(var i=0; i<models.length; i++){
    var model=models[i];
    if(model.model === 'res.company'){
         model.fields.push('street');
         model.fields.push('city');
         model.fields.push('state_id');
         model.fields.push('country_id');

         // other field you want to pull from the res.company table.

    } 
}
```

Then you will get it in the `company:this.pos.company`.

Now you can use it in template eg. `company.street, company.city` etc.

For country and state use company.state_id[1] and company.country_id[1] in template.

Comment: yes this is working for me but actually, i wan't the address details of company and it's not in res_company so how can i fetch the street and other address from res_partner for company ?

Comment: You mean you want address detail of company not partner?

Comment: yes i wan't the address  detail of company. i try to fetch the address using company object but it's doesn't contain address detail for company in res_company table.

Comment: I updated my answer. you need to add address fields in to the models to access it in pos.